# NSLinguisticTagger on the contents of an NSTextStorage- crashing bug

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstextstorage

I'm trying to use an NSLinguisticTagger to monitor the contents of an NSTextStorage and provide some contextual information based on what the user types. To that end, I have an OverlayManager object, which wires up this relationship:

```
-(void) setView:(NSTextView*) view {
    _view = view;
    _layout = view.layoutManager;
    _storage = view.layoutManager.textStorage; //get the TextStorage from the view
    [_tagger setString:_storage.string]; //pull the string out, this grabs the mutable version
    [self registerForNotificationsOn:self->_storage]; //subscribe to the willProcessEditing notification
}
```

When an edit occurs, I make sure to trap it and notify the tagger (and yes, I know I'm being annoyingly inconsistent with member access, I'm rusty on Obj-C, I'll fix it later):

```
- (void) textStorageWillProcessEditing:(NSNotification*) notification{
    if ([self->_storage editedMask] & NSTextStorageEditedCharacters) {
        NSRange editedRange = [self->_storage editedRange];
        NSUInteger delta = [self->_storage changeInLength];
        [_tagger stringEditedInRange:editedRange changeInLength:delta]; //should notify the tagger of the changes- if I replace this line with [_tagger setString:[_storage string]] it works, but gobbles CPU as it retags the entire string
        [self highlightEdits:self];
    }
}
```

The highlightEdits message delegates the job out to a pool of "Overlay" objects. Each contains a block of code similar to this:

```
[tagger enumerateTagsInRange:range scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLexicalClass options:0 usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {
            if (tag == PartOfSpeech) {
                [self applyHighlightToRange:tokenRange onStorage:storage];
            }
        }];
```

And that's where the problem is- the enumerateTagsInRange method crashes out with a message:

```
2014-06-04 10:07:19.692 WritersEditor[40191:303] NSMutableRLEArray     replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds
```

This problem *doesn't* occur if I don't link to the mutable copy of the underlying string and instead do a `[[_storage string] copy]`, but obviously I don't want to copy the entire backing store every time I want to do tagging. This all should be happening in the main run loop, so I don't think this is a threading issue. The NSRange I'm enumerating tags on exists both in the NSTextStorage *and* in the NSLinguisticTagger's view of the string. It's not even the fact that the applyHighlightToRange call adds attributes to the string, because it crashes before even reaching that line.

I attempted to build a test case around the problem, but can't replicate it in those situations:

```
- (void) testEdit
{
    NSAttributedString* str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Quickly, this is a test."];
    text = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:str];

    NSArray* schemes = [NSLinguisticTagger availableTagSchemesForLanguage:@"en"];
    tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:schemes options:0];
    [tagger setString:[text string]];

    [text beginEditing];
    [[text mutableString] appendString:@"T"];
    NSRange edited = [text editedRange];
    NSUInteger length = [text changeInLength];
    [text endEditing];

    [tagger stringEditedInRange:edited changeInLength:length];
    [tagger enumerateTagsInRange:edited scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLexicalClass options:0 usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {
        //doesn't matter, this should crash
    }];
}
```

That code *doesn't* crash.

Comment: I suspect you're incorrect when you say that `-applyHighlightToRange:...` hasn't run because it crashes before that. I suspect one iteration of the enumeration has run and it's on a subsequent iteration that it crashes. In that second iteration, it may be before that call, but that doesn't mean it was before all such calls. You can put a log message just before that call as a test.

Comment: I've been using breakpoints to make sure it doesn't hit that line (and I can 100% guarantee that the guard condition on it is never passed). FWIW, I can get it to bomb out before it ever reaches that point by using the `-sentenceForRange` method on the Tagger. The exception is the same.